# Ajax sends two files at one time through one onclick event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

jQuery AJAX seems to be sending two requests at once when I use the onclick event with JavaScript in a tag.  I click once, and that seems ok, but when I change the id value to an invalid id value, it sends two requests to the PHP file.  I think the problem may be caused by the browser caching JavaScript code.
Here's is the JavaScript code I'm using to generate the query:

```
function unlike_image(id, image_id, obj) {
    var url_unlike_image = base_url + 'profile/unlike_image';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:
        {
            user_id:  id,
            image_id: image_id
        },
        url: url_unlike_image,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.status=='error_exists') {
                alert('This image not exists');
            }

            if (data.status=='success') {
                //like = like - 1 for view
                var str = $(obj).next().text();
                var n = str.length;
                str_like = str.substring(1, n-1);
                var number_likes = parseInt(str_like) - 1;

                $(obj).next().text('('+number_likes+')');
                //change event click unlike
                $(obj).text('Like');
                $(obj).attr('onclick', 'like_image('+id+' ,'+image_id+ ',this); return false');
            }

        }
    });
}
```

After changing the true id to the wrong id,  I check the website traffic, I see two instances where unlike_image is called. The first is with the true id, and the second is with the wrong id.

Comment: I think, we'll need the code that triggers unlike_image()

Comment: Can I fix this error with onclick event? someButton.addEventListener('click', function() {}); is this ok?

Comment: Nothing shown would cause function to fire twice. Show usage of function. Where is the invalid id being used?

Comment: Sorry, <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="id_<?php echo $u['id']; ?>" onclick="unlike_image(<?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_id');?>, <?php echo $image['id']; ?>, this); return false">Unlike</a><span class="red_like_lable">(<?php echo $image['number_like']; ?>)</span>

Comment: Check that you dont have 2 elements with the same id.

Comment: @dariogriffo I don't think that would do it. Only 1 id is valid as far as javascript is concerned.

Comment: @colecmc, Yes, just only one id, I think i had cached and i find something to fix this, but not work

Comment: @joe1234 usually this `$(obj).attr('onclick', 'like_image('+id+' ,'+image_id+ ',this); return false');` is done like that `$(obj).click(function () {like_image(id, image_id, this); return false;});` other than that we really need the other function or more information in general

Comment: @maraca. thank for solution, but not work. In current method,  I still like and unlike normal, just call unlike_image and like_image and so on. Only send two file to server when i change to invalid id_image. And i follow you, but not work normal anymore, appear two file send to server athought i dont change to invalid id.